# unsure of the error in syntax of my code "expected an indented block"

Tags: python-2.7

Im confused as to where the errors in my syntax are occuring. I'm new to coding and am trying to learn but im lost here. the error is occuring after the 
def fun2(n):  during the if 0<=n: statement. if you would be kind to point out any other errors in my code it would be appreicated. for reference I am using python 2.7.9.

EDIT: I had forgotten about my established main function. that was the source of my syntax error due to my inner functions not being tabbed. Thank you to those who answered.

```
def main():

def fun(n):
    func= (n**3)-1

def fun2(n):
    for i in range(n):
        if 0<=n:
            func2 += i*fun(i)
        if 0 > n:
            func2 = 0

def fun3(m,n):
    c3=[]
    if m<=n:
        C3.append[func2(n)]
    if m>n:
        c3=[]
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is based on tabs and spaces, and you've got a line of code that is more intended than python would like it to be. Its not possible to see from your code above, but an IDE like pyCharm or a text editor like sublime text could help you out here.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that you are consistently using tabs or consistently using spaces.  Python doesn't like to mix the two, and even if you press only the tab key, sometimes your computer still puts in 4 or 5 spaces instead.

This is especially a problem if you copy and pasted some of the code from somewhere--who knows whether that pasted code used spaces or tabs?

Comment: my issue is no matter if i rewrote the code into a separate file making sure to only use tabs and the correct amount needed. python still recognizes this as a syntax error. and when i go to look at the code my self. it just automatically uses 4 spaces. or it. im sure thats the issue but im clueless how to fix it.

Comment: scratch that. I found the error. I had forgotten that i had established a main function which ended up being the cause of the syntax error. my functions in the main function as listed in my question were not indented. thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!